# Variables get cleared after jquery POST

Tags: javascript, jquery

There must be something I don't understand about how jquery post works because the following code does not behave the way I expect it.

```
var list = [];
$.post("list", function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        list.push({label: data[i].label, value: data[i].value});
        alert(list[0].value);
    }
});
alert(list[0].value);
```

Note the two alerts, the first alert has a value, the second is "undefined" why? How could I get around this? I had the same issue with $.get and $.ajax so I must be doing something wrong. I tried searching it but I didn't find anything really.

**UPDATE:**

```
var templeList = [];
$.ajax({
        url: "templeList", 
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                templeList.push({label: data[i].label, value: data[i].value});
                alert(templeList[0].value);
            }
        },
        cache: true,
        async:false
});
alert(templeList[0].value);
```

This code solves it, thanks for the quick response

Comment: Ajax is **asynchronous**.

Comment: oops... I knew that of course but didn't think about what that meant in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function inside `$.post` is a callback -- it runs asynchronously (after the response is received from the server).  That means the second alert actually gets called first, before `list` is set.

To get around this, you typically would place the second alert inside its own function, which you then invoke from inside the async callback:

```
var list = [];
$.post("list", function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        list.push({label: data[i].label, value: data[i].value});
        alert(list[0].value);
    }
    onReady();
});

function onReady() {
    alert(list[0].value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

post method is asynchronous one, this mean that your code executed in following way:

1. init empty list
2. send request to server
3. try to alert with empty list
4. after some time when data comes, your function is really called
5. list is populated and "first" alert provide proper results